# iMac with Mavericks sometimes won't sleep

Tags: imac, sleep-wake

My mid 2012 iMac 27" with Mavericks sometimes won't sleep. Its screen is light up in the morning and I'm still logged in.
Energy settings:
[image]

pmset shows:

```
Last login: Wed Jan 22 23:08:58 on ttys000
renes-imac:~ rene$ pmset -g
Active Profiles:
AC Power        -1*
Currently in use:
 hibernatemode        0
 halfdim              1
 womp                 1
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                20 (sleep prevented by coreaudiod, backupd, backupd)
 Sleep On Power Button 1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 autorestart          0
 disksleep            10
 displaysleep         15
```

I am running Windows 8.1 in Parallels 9. But that's always running. So I doubt it's Windows fault. Is there anything I can do to analyze why it did not sleep?

Comment: sleep prevented by coreaudiod, backupd, backupd <--

Comment: I know. How to find out *why* it is doing that and *what* exactly causes the issue?

Comment: Google: https://discussions.apple.com/message/16238880#16238880

Answer (score 1):

`backupd` is most of Time Machine. I think your computer is constantly backing up over a slowish network link such as WiFi.

I suspect that you have a large amount of file changes every day. Is the Windows image you are running in in Parallels being backed up? That could do it? Go into `System Preferences` > `Time Machine` and click on `Options...`

This will allow you to exclude your image files from Time Machine.

If that doesn't work turn off `Time Machine` for a couple of days and see if the computer sleeps.

Comment: Good hint. I have now optimized PD for integration with Time Machine. http://kb.parallels.com/de/8827